# Complete list of Cocoa string format specifiers

Tags: string, cocoa-touch, cocoa, string-formatting

I am studying Objective-C and would like to compile a complete list of String Format Specifiers.

I have used Google to find a simple list, but would like to expand on this. I have drawn resources from books, the Apple Developer website, and through university, but I want a complete list of the specifiers available in a table format.

Apple's own [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) article isn't exhaustive enough nor does it give these specifiers with examples.

The image below is the kind of table I'd be interested in finding if it's available, or point me to an article that lists all these and more. As a starting point the table below doesn't specify `%s` for "string" *(as an example)*.

[image]

Comment: The Apple doc you linked itself links directly to the canonical list: [the IEEE/POSIX printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C, so just compile a list of all the C specifiers then add `%@` and you are done.

Comment: To log an actual percent sign you do `%%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just like in c (or c++). For example you find a list here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/